# Events stop triggering after a while

Tags: web3js, events, nodejs, infura

I created a script that subscribes to PairCreated event on Uniswap using Web3 and Infura API.
The event works for a few minutes but stops working after a while (timeouts?). How can I make it watch the event indefinitely?

```
uniswapV2FactoryContract.events.PairCreated({})
  .on('data', async function(event){
    const token0 = new web3.eth.Contract(IERC20.abi, event.returnValues.token0);
    const token1 = new web3.eth.Contract(IERC20.abi, event.returnValues.token1);

    console.log(`New pair on Uniswap V2: ${await token0.methods.symbol().call()} ${event.returnValues.token0} - ${await token1.methods.symbol().call()} ${event.returnValues.token1}!`);
  })
  .on('error', console.error);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add options to your websocket constructor

```
const options = {
    timeout: 30000, // ms

    clientConfig: {
        // Useful if requests are large
        maxReceivedFrameSize: 100000000,   // bytes - default: 1MiB
        maxReceivedMessageSize: 100000000, // bytes - default: 8MiB

        // Useful to keep a connection alive
        keepalive: true,
        keepaliveInterval: -1 // ms
    },

    // Enable auto reconnection
    reconnect: {
        auto: true,
        delay: 1000, // ms
        maxAttempts: 10,
        onTimeout: false
    }
};

// Connect
let provider, web3;
provider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("your websocket url", options);
web3 = new Web3(provider);
```